# VSFTP path with backslash

Tags: windows, ftp, centos

**Short Version:** Is there a way to tell VSFTP to convert a backslash delimited path to a forward slash path?

**Long Version:**  We're building an FTP machine on CENTOS using VSFTP to replace an existing windows server that we'd like to stop paying the Microsoft Tax on (i.e. not pay for the windows license)

The goal is to switch traffic from the old FTP with as little maintenance on the client end as possible. Several of the "in the wild" clients have backslash delimited paths which currently work fine on the windows FTP server - but throw "Cannot Change Directory" errors when pointed at this new Linux machine.

Workaround: We have a workaround in place but it's UGLY - it involves creating the paths in question with backslashes and linking them to the correct directories.

Example:

- FTP Client wants to get to
  `\clientName\clientDataDirectory`
- We create on the linux box
  `/ftproot/clientName/clientDataDirectory`
- We also create a symbolic where we
  type it in like this `/ftproot/\\clientName\\clientDataDirectory`

I was kind of hoping for a switch in the vsftpd.conf file like `convert-backslashed-path` or something.

Comment: Our new printer/scanner (Xerox workcentre) has the ability to upload scans to an ftp server, but creates filepaths using the backslash character ("<date>\file.pdf"). It would be great if vsftpd could convert this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this with VSFTPD. You will have to cludge your files ystem or change your scripts. It should be fairly easy to modify your scripts using sed or awk.